# Can't get GLEW working with VS2010, linker errors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl, linker, glew

I'm trying to learn OpenGL and using openglbook.com as my reference. I'm trying to get GLEW and freeglut to work on my computer, and so I'm starting out by going through the steps he lays out for getting them working with Visual Studio here: http://openglbook.com/setting-up-opengl-glew-and-freeglut-in-visual-c. I'm following it to the letter and the only difference is that I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

The issue appears when I try to use GLEW; when this happens I get a linker error. Here's the full text of the error message:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: gl1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 2012/07/28 20:12:19.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\gl1.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glewGetErrorString@4 referenced in function _Initialize
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glewInit@0 referenced in function _Initialize
1>c:\users\magpie\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\gl1\Debug\gl1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.84
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any help? When I first encountered this error, I tried compiling GLEW from source, but that didn't fix it either (assuming I did that correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that the compiler cannot find the implementation of the methods described in the header file. To statically compile GLEW with your application, add the glew32.lib file to the library search directories (project properties -> VC search directories).